# How can I run my ruby on rails project through an executable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exe

I need to be able to run my ruby project through a build script (sort of like what ANT xml files do for Java). I am new to Ruby on Rails and am not sure if this is even possible for this particular language.

I hope that it will be able to, when given a zip file of my project, run the executable and have the project work on their PC. Is this possible to do for ruby? If so, which commands should I include in the file? (ex. db:migrate, bundle install, etc)

Comment: Like all things, it's certainly possible but not without a massive number of hoops to jump through. It sounds like you might be using the wrong tool for the wrong job.

Comment: Can you please explain why you want to do that? maybe for local development or something similar?